# Custom Android ListView

Tags: android, list, view

I'm new to the this excellent site and in the Java programming Android. I started to make a small test application for the listing of my favorite places in my town. I tried to follow some tutorials on different pages, but when I do I put in my project in Eclipse always gives me more than a million mistakes although imports classes and other methods.

I want to build on the example image discotheque next to the image name discos and under that name Diskotek smaller text additional info.

It would be really grateful for all the help

Comment: Help with what? you didn't ask a question or give us any details on the problem you're having

Comment: The question was: How can I create a ListView like that one i explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Custom ListView` requires total 4 basic stuff 2 in design (`layout .xml`) & 2 class (`.java`)

**2 Layout**
a) Basically a container which has a `listview` with either a heading or button depends on you
b) How each row should look like should they have `buttons`, `images`, `textview` how ever you want.

**2 Java Class File**
a) One is the `Activity` which you will have definitely.
b) `Custom Adapter` which says which value from your `Activity` will go to which `View` (`Button , image` ) depending on your requirement.

The best example is to follow this [**Tutorial**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: It was exactly that, what I asked for. thank you very much sir!

Comment: @Andro then please do +1 it :D Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I think when someone says 'I tried to follow some tutorials...' but they don't work, It gets kind of hard to believe.

- Where's the code you tried?
- What are the import errors on the editor?

That'd be an easier problem to address.

To give you a simple ListView example:

First, create a resource file at your preference: (example.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/disco_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/disco_title"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/disco_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/disco_info"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/disco_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/disco_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, create a custom adapter, they are very simple. Just extend a BaseAdapter for now.

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//Let's create some constants first, to fill out the rows
private static final String [] DISCO_NAMES = {"Disco One", "Disco Two", "Disco Three", "Disco Four"};
private static final String [] DISCO_INFO = {"Some Info One", "Some Info Two", "Some Info Three", "Some Info Four"};

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

//Our custom adapter needs a constructor, so you can create from your activity.
public ExampleAdapter (final Context context) {
    //for now, let's just get the context, we'll need it to inflate views
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //this needs to return to the amount of rows you want to display.
    //right now we return a fixed value, this could vary based on your needs
    return DISCO_NAMES.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    //this is useful for knowing what item is at what position
    //for now, let's just return the disco name shall we?
    return DISCO_NAMES[pos];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    //This returns an id to the item
    //personally I don't use this, so you can just return the position
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    //Ha, here's the important part
    //ListViews reuse rows, so let's check if the view (also known as convertview) is new or being reused
    if (view == null) {
        //this means it's a new view, so we need to inflate it
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.example, null);
    }
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disco_title)).setText(DISCO_NAMES[position]);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disco_info)).setText(DISCO_INFO[position]);
    //You can also set some images to the imageview on the layout we created earlier
    return view;
    }
}
```

Then, let's create a ListActivity for example purposes. **NOTE** ListActivit does not require a Layout Resource to be set via setContentView, so we don't call it here.

```
public class ExampleListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //create the adapter
    ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(this);

    //fill the listView
    setListAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
    }
}
```

That should compile as is, but you may want to look into ViewHolder patterns and blah blah blah for performance reasons. Obviously you need to read more, but I hope this helps as a starting point.